# Need more explanation about what's being done here?

Tags: perl

```
print reverse <>;
print sort <>;
```

What's the exact steps perl handles with these operations?

It seems for the `1st` one,perl not just reverses the order of invocation parameters,but also the contents of each file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 print reverse <>;
```

`<>` is evaluated in an array context, meaning it "slurps" the file.  It reads the entire file.  In the case of the magic file represented by the files named in @ARGV, it will read the contents of all files in the order referenced by the command line arguments (@ARGV).

`reverse` then reverses the order of the array, meaning the last line from the last file comes first, and the first line from the last file comes last.

`print` then prints the array.

From your notes, you might want something like this:

```
perl -e 'sub BEGIN { @ARGV=reverse @ARGV; } print <>;' /etc/motd /etc/passwd
```

Comment: An array is a variable type; you mean "evaluated in list context", "reverses the order of the list", "then prints the list".

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the [docs for I/O operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators). Here's an excerpt from the docs:

> The null filehandle <> is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk. Input from <> comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time <> is evaluated, the @ARGV array is checked, and if it is empty, $ARGV[0] is set to "-", which when opened gives you standard input. The @ARGV array is then processed as a list of filenames.

It's worth reading the entire doc, as it provides equivalent "non-magical" Perl code equivalent to `<>` in various use cases.